# The function 'CreateTime' is not supported by SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce-4

I wanted to change my code-first project to SQL Server Compact 4.0.

But I have a problem with following LINQ expression

```
db.Test.OrderBy(t => t.Name)
       .ThenBy(t => t.DayOfWeek)
       .ThenBy(t => DbFunctions.CreateTime(t.TimeFrom.Hour, t.TimeFrom.Minute, t.TimeFrom.Second))
```

It throws the following error

> The function 'CreateTime' is not supported by SQL Server Compact

Is there a way to write that expression without using the `CreateTime` method?

Comment: Can you try `ThenBy(t => t.TimeFrom.Hour * 3600 + t.TimeFrom.Minute * 60 + t.TimeFrom.Second)`?

Comment: Another option is to use `ThenBy(t => t.TimeFrom.Hour).ThenBy(t => t.TimeFrom.Minute).ThenBy(t => t.TimeFrom.Second)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using code-first with Sql Server Compact. In my model I have a property called TimeStamp of type DateTime. At then I could do:

```
db.Test.OrderBy(t => t.Name)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.Hour)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.Minute)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.Second)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.Millisecond);
```

or

```
db.Test.OrderBy(t => t.Name)
   .ThenBy(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks);
```

Comment: I get the error: The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: I edited my answer to use Hour, Minute... etc instead of TimeOfDay